# PHP MYSQL How to select product via product filters from other table

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

I have two tables:

products:

[image: products]

And table filters:

[image: filters values]

How to create searching via one input name array: `name="specifications[]"` and select all product matched to your search?

ads_id have only one id product. SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ads_id

I try create function which create data for query (AND ... AND ... AND ...)

Function:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `filters_values` WHERE ";

            if(empty($get['specifications'])){
                $spec = null;
            }else{
                $spec = $get['specifications'];
            }
            
            $i = 0;
            if($spec != null){
                foreach($spec as $data){
                    $i++;
                    $data = explode(',', $data);
                    
                    if(isset($data['1'])){
                        echo 'Szukam w id filtra <b>'.$data[0].'</b> z wartością <b>'.$data['1'].'</b><br/><br/>';
                        if($i > 1){
                            $query .= " OR `value` LIKE '%".$data['1']."%' ";
                        }else{
                            $query .= "`value` LIKE '%".$data['1']."%' ";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $i = ($i - 1);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            $query .= " GROUP BY `ads_id`";

            if($i == 0){
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM `filters_values`';
            }
```

When user send formulage:

```
array(6) { 
    ["categoryId"]=> string(5) " 1 " 
    ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["region"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["Przebieg_(KM)"]=> string(2) "34" 
    ["specifications"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "1,34" 
        [1]=> string(4) "2,11" 
        [2]=> string(7) "3,jakas" 
        [3]=> string(4) "4,bb" 
    } 
    ["Wpisz_coś"]=> string(2) "11" 
}
```

`3,jakas" [3]=> string(4) "4,bb`
number is a filter id jakas or bb is a filter value

Full function:

```
public static function getAds($get){

        
                
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `filters_values` WHERE ";

            if(empty($get['specifications'])){
                $spec = null;
            }else{
                $spec = $get['specifications'];
            }
            
            $i = 0;
            if($spec != null){
                foreach($spec as $data){
                    $i++;
                    $data = explode(',', $data);
                    
                    if(isset($data['1'])){
                        echo 'Szukam w id filtra <b>'.$data[0].'</b> z wartością <b>'.$data['1'].'</b><br/><br/>';
                        if($i > 1){
                            $query .= " OR `value` LIKE '%".$data['1']."%' ";
                        }else{
                            $query .= "`value` LIKE '%".$data['1']."%' ";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $i = ($i - 1);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            $query .= " GROUP BY `ads_id`";

            if($i == 0){
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM `filters_values`';
            }
            
            echo '<br/><Br/>Koncowe zapytanie: '.$query;

            $db = new Database();
            $db->query($query);
            $db->execute();

            echo '<br/><b>Tytuły znalezionych ['.$db->rowCount().'] ogłoszeń:</b><br/><br/>';

            foreach($db->resultSet() as $data){
                if($db->rowCount() > 0){
                    
                        $query = ("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE `id` = :id ");

                        if(!empty($_GET['categoryId']) && $_GET['categoryId'] > 0){
                            $query .= " AND `category_id` = :cat";
                        }

                        $db->query($query);

                        if(!empty($_GET['categoryId']) && $_GET['categoryId'] > 0){
                            $db->bind(':cat', $_GET['categoryId']);
                        }

                        $db->bind(':id', $data['ads_id']);
                    
                    foreach($db->resultSet() as $key){
                        echo '- '.$key['name'].'<br/>';
                    }
                }
            }

        
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you edit the question and add it to the bottom of it?

Comment: How are those tables related?

Comment: So i added code how to i wanted creating function... And not work. User send array specifications[] from input and script make search on table filters. Next select data from product based on what it found in the filters

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors? (If so, please post them in your question) What is `$get`?

Comment: @brombeer i added array to topic when user send formulage and this is get. No show any data, no error.

Comment: @brombeer and added full function search

Comment: There does not appear to be a clear relationship between the two tables shown - are there other columns within the `products` table that you have not shown or is that it and  there really is no relationship?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Another rows in table product they have no meaning. Simply, if filters are selected, I want the code to search first by filters and take the ads_id from the filters table and show the products.

Comment: But how is the `ads_id` related to your products?

Comment: @brombeer ads_id have only one id product. SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = `ads_id`

Comment: This just smacks of poor database design - missing one of the fundamental aspects of RDBMS where the R is the important part of that acronym.

Comment: @VaderStudents Please add that info to your question, that's quite confusing. Most people would expect your `ads_id` to be named `product_id`

Comment: @brombeer added

Comment: Not quite sure if i understand what's going on here? So if you query `SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ads_id`, and your filter ids are 1,2,3,4 which makes the ads_id as 4 so that gets you only 1 product?

Comment: Look, i select more records from table filters, filter have value and ads_id. Ads_id = product id. User put data to input. I want select all records from filters who have values from input. If find filters select product from table product with id from filters. If not find records - show all

Comment: @brombeer
@Adi
@ProfessorAbronsius

I create this code, and work...
```
$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ads p LEFT JOIN filters_values f ON p.id = f.ads_id WHERE p.name LIKE '%bbb%' AND p.category_id='3' AND f.value='test' GROUP BY p.id");
```